# Vue router dynamic component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, import, vuejs2, vue-router

I am stuck with vue-router at some part that I dont know what to do anymore and cant find anything that would work me, I am not sure if its for older versions or something else.

**My problem:**
I have an Vue app for 2 different websites,for example: *example.nl* and *example.be* . 
Now for both sites I have an siteId. I can get that id from vuex.

```
const siteId = store.getters.siteId;
```

Now based on the siteId I want to load a component on a route.

**Example**:

```
import {store} from '@/plugins/vuex_store';

const siteId = store.getters.siteId;
import test from 'nl/test'; 


if(siteId === 2) {
    import test from 'be/test'; <-- thows error 'statement expected'.
}

let router = ({
    path: 'exmaple',
    name: 'example',
    component: test,
});

export default router;
```

I tried couple of things like:

```
import("nl/test").then(foo => console.log(foo.default));
```

But that gives me an syntax error.

Any ideas would be nice

Answer (score 2):

I might have 3 solutions for you. I am myself unsure with solution 2.

```
const siteId = store.getters.siteId;
let loadSite = () => import ('nl/test'); 


if(siteId === 2) {
    loadSite = () => import ('be/test'); 
}

let router = ({
    path: 'exmaple',
    name: 'example',
    component: loadSite,
});
```

or

```
const siteId = store.getters.siteId;
const loadSite1 = () => import ('nl/test'); 
const loadSite2 = () => import ('be/test'); 

let router = ({
    path: 'exmaple',
    name: 'example',
    component: (siteId === 1) ? loadSite1 : loadSite2,
});
```

or

```
    const loadSite1 = () => import ('nl/test'); 
    const loadSite2 = () => import ('be/test'); 

    let router = ({
        path: 'example',
        name: 'example',
    }, {
        path: 'site1',
        name: 'site1',
        component: loadSite1,
    }, {
        path: 'site2',
        name: 'site2',
        component: loadSite2,
    });

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
   if (to.path.example === 'example') {
      if(store.getters.siteId === 1) return next('site1');
      else if(store.getters.siteId === 2) return next('site2');
   }
}
```

Comment: This does not work for me cause I get an syntax error on compiling like I describe in my question. I tried an new CLI 3 project and there is does work, so I think I need to upgrade to a newer Vue project template

Comment: You `router.js` import should look like this:
`import Vue from "vue";`   `import Router from "vue-router";` . What is the syntax error you get?